# How to save timeline list of events in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I try to use flutter timeline package, but I don't successed to save and load the list of events with sharedpreference

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_timeline

here is my code and what I expect to do

[Edit] here is code with add of futur builder that I think I need but don't sur

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_timeline/flutter_timeline.dart';
import 'package:flutter_timeline/indicator_position.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(TimelineDemoApp());
}

class TimelineDemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Timeline',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),

      home: PlainTimelineDemoScreen(),
    );
  }
}




class PlainTimelineDemoScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _PlainTimelineDemoScreenState();
}

class _PlainTimelineDemoScreenState extends State<PlainTimelineDemoScreen> {
  List<TimelineEventDisplay> events;

  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeDateFormatting("fr_FR", null);

    super.initState();
    load_timeline();
    events = [
      plainEventDisplay,
    ];
  }


  String Data1;
  String Data2;

  save_timeline() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      prefs.setString('timeline', events);
    });
  }
  
  load_timeline() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {

      events = prefs.getString('timeline');
    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Timeline test"),
      ),
      body:  FutureBuilder(
        future: load_timeline(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return _buildTimeline();
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator(); // or some other widget
        },
      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _addEvent,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }




  TimelineEventDisplay get plainEventDisplay {
    var currentTime = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(DateTime.now());


    return TimelineEventDisplay(
      anchor: IndicatorPosition.top,
      indicatorOffset: Offset(0, 0),
      child: TimelineEventCard(
          title: Text("${currentTime}"),
          content:  Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text("description1 : $Data1"),  
              Text("description2 : $Data2"),


            ],
          )
      ),
      indicator:       TimelineDots.of(context).circleIcon,
    );
  }


  Widget _buildTimeline() {
    return TimelineTheme(
        data: TimelineThemeData(
            lineColor: Colors.blueAccent, itemGap: 5, lineGap: 0),
        child: Timeline(
          anchor: IndicatorPosition.center,
          indicatorSize: 56,
          altOffset: Offset(10, 10),
          events: events,
        ));
  }

  void _addEvent() {
    setState(() {
      //currently in this example data1 and data2 or static
      //after, here user will modify Data1 and data2 with textfield and save is text in save_timeline()
      save_timeline();
      events.add(plainEventDisplay);

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this question need more focus. Maybe rephrase the question in a shorter, clearer manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting `List<TimelineEventDisplay>` directly to / from `String` does not work:

```
List<TimelineEventDisplay> events;
...
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString('timeline', events);
...
events = prefs.getString('timeline');
```

You need a way to serialize/deserialize the relevant data about the events.
In your case, those seem to be the datetime of the event and the two descriptions.

You can model those with a class and include support functions for converting the object to / from JSON:

```
class EventData {
  final DateTime dateTime;
  final String data1;
  final String data2;

  EventData(this.dateTime, this.data1, this.data2);

  EventData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : dateTime = DateTime.parse(json['dateTime']),
        data1 = json['data1'],
        data2 = json['data2'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'dateTime': dateTime.toIso8601String(),
    'data1': data1,
    'data2': data2,
  };
}
```

You can then keep the data about the events as `List<EventData> eventsData`.

Storing event data as JSON in the `save_timeline` function:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var json = jsonEncode(eventsData);
prefs.setString('timeline', json);
```

Loading event data from JSON in the `load_timeline` function:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var json = prefs.getString('timeline');
var items = jsonDecode(json) as List;
eventsData = items.map((i) => EventData.fromJson(i)).toList();
```

Then finally, when you want to display the events, you can render each `EventData` into a `TimelineEventDisplay` using the `plainEventDisplay` function.

**Full example:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_timeline/flutter_timeline.dart';
import 'package:flutter_timeline/indicator_position.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  runApp(TimelineDemoApp());
}

class TimelineDemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Timeline',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: PlainTimelineDemoScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class PlainTimelineDemoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _PlainTimelineDemoScreenState();
}

class _PlainTimelineDemoScreenState extends State<PlainTimelineDemoScreen> {
  List<EventData> eventsData;
  List<TimelineEventDisplay> events;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeDateFormatting("fr_FR", null);
  }

  String Data1;
  String Data2;

  save_timeline() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //serialize event data to json
    var json = jsonEncode(eventsData);
    await prefs.setString('timeline', json);
  }

  load_timeline() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var json = prefs.getString('timeline');
    if (json == null) {
      //no data available
      eventsData = [];
    } else {
      //deserialize event data from json
      var items = jsonDecode(json) as List;
      eventsData = items.map((i) => EventData.fromJson(i)).toList();
    }
    //render event data
    events = eventsData.map(plainEventDisplay).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Timeline test"),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: load_timeline(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return _buildTimeline();
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _addEvent,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  TimelineEventDisplay plainEventDisplay(EventData eventData) {
    var formattedTime = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(eventData.dateTime);

    return TimelineEventDisplay(
      anchor: IndicatorPosition.top,
      indicatorOffset: Offset(0, 0),
      child: TimelineEventCard(
          title: Text("${formattedTime}"),
          content: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text("description1 : ${eventData.data1}"),
              Text("description2 : ${eventData.data2}"),
            ],
          )),
      indicator: TimelineDots.of(context).circleIcon,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTimeline() {
    return TimelineTheme(
        data: TimelineThemeData(
            lineColor: Colors.blueAccent, itemGap: 5, lineGap: 0),
        child: Timeline(
          anchor: IndicatorPosition.center,
          indicatorSize: 56,
          altOffset: Offset(10, 10),
          events: events,
        ));
  }

  void _addEvent() {
    //currently in this example data1 and data2 or static
    //after, here user will modify Data1 and data2 with textfield and save is text in save_timeline()
    Data1 = "data1 from " + DateTime.now().toIso8601String();
    Data2 = "data2 from " + DateTime.now().toIso8601String();
    var eventData = EventData(DateTime.now(), Data1, Data2);
    eventsData.add(eventData);
    save_timeline();
    //trigger refresh
    setState(() {});
  }
}

class EventData {
  final DateTime dateTime;
  final String data1;
  final String data2;

  EventData(this.dateTime, this.data1, this.data2);

  EventData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : dateTime = DateTime.parse(json['dateTime']),
        data1 = json['data1'],
        data2 = json['data2'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'dateTime': dateTime.toIso8601String(),
    'data1': data1,
    'data2': data2,
  };
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you, it's work perfectly, I will now start to work with this